# ResourceLink element in Tomcat is not working

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, tomcat7, jndi

I am using apache-tomcat-7.0.35.I have defined an environment variable in server.xml as below

```
<GlobalNamingResources>

        <Environment name="sam" 
                 value="D:\AppServers\apache-tomcat-7.0.35\conf\sample.xml"
                 type="java.lang.String" override="true"/>

  </GlobalNamingResources>
```

I am using ResourceLink element in side my context element in context.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context path="/Practice_1" docBase="/Practice_1"
    crossContext="true" reloadable="true" debug="1">
<ResourceLink name="sam" global="sam" type="java.lang.String"/>

</Context>
```

When I try to get this valuue in the code using

```
 Context initCtx = new InitialContext();
        String configPath = (String)initCtx.lookup("sam");
```

Its throwing `javax.naming.NameNotFoundException.javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [sam] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [sam].`

How can I rectify this?

Answer (score 2):

tomcat jndi has default name space "java:comp/env".

Modify your code to either

```
Context initCtx = new InitialContext();
String configPath = (String)initCtx.lookup("java:comp/env/sam");
```

or

```
Context initCtx = new InitialContext();
Context rootCtx = (Context) initCtx.lookup("java:comp/env");
String configPath = (String)rootCtx.lookup("sam");
```

Answer (score 1):

If i am not wrong you dont need to modify the server.xml .

Modified context.xml

```
<Resource auth="Container"            java.naming.factory.initial="org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContextFactory" 
factory="de.example.CXIResourceLocator"
name="bean/CXIResourceLocator"
type="de.example.Bean"/>
```

web.xml

```
<resource-env-ref>
    <description>
        Connection pooling.
    </description>
    <resource-env-ref-name>bean/CXIResourceLocator</resource-env-ref-name>
    <resource-env-ref-type>
        de.example.Bean
    </resource-env-ref-type>
</resource-env-ref>

bean/CXIResourceLocator should match in both context and web xmls.
```

Since I dont know your purpose of doing this, I cant help you more. :-(

Follow this link for more details. Apache gave very good example.

hope this help.
http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/jndi-resources-howto.html